# What effects are there to using law enforcer #1?

Tags: neocron

Each new character created in Neocron is 'born' with a LAW Enforcer #1 CPU in one of their implant slots. Is this something that I should keep in or should I remove it? what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LAW Enforcer (or LE) essentially blocks you from being able to attack other players in game. It also prevents other players from attacking you. There are pros and cons to the LAW Enforcer as follows;

Pros:

- You cannot be attacked by other players
- When you die, you do not drop a quickbelt
- Prevents any accidental loss of soullight or faction sympathy from other players running through any area of effect attacks you do

Cons:

- You cannot join a clan
- You cannot attack other players (not always a con)
- It takes up an implant slot that could be used for another brain implant

Removing the LAW Enforcer is easy, simply drag it out of the brain implant slot it is in to your inventory and this will start an implant process to remove it. It will take quite a while to remove, but it can be re-implanted at any point provided your skill rank is /30 or below. Above a skill rank of /30 it is no longer possible to re-implant a LAW Enforcer.

You do not need any skill points in the implant (+IMP) ability to insert a LAW Enforcer.

Comment: thanks somebody said in ooc that you also get less xp and credits with it in is this true

Comment: not anymore no - originally the LAW enforcer resulted in a small percentage of any cash you earned by killing enemies to be deducted from the total you earned but this is no longer the case - the LAW enforcer is purely an anti-PvP measure now